# What to include in file to handle associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have special method in `array.rb`, which I want to add to array's instance objects.

Basically, it iterates through collection of new records and saves it in one transaction.

```
#@items.list_transaction
```

in controller.

```
include ActiveRecord
class Array
  def list_transaction
    errors=[]
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      self.each do |list_item|
        unless list_item.save  #&& yield(list_item).save
          errors << list_item.errors
        end
      end
    end

    if errors.any?
       errors
    else
      true
    end

  end
end
```

What I noticed, as this code is not part of controller/model, it does not handle associations.

For example, If I put exact same code inside of controller, on `list_item.save` it will also validate associated with `list_item` `account`, but as I place it in separate file, I need to add this commented part: `yield(list_item).save` where block refers to `list_item.account.save`, or Rails just skips this.

Same thing with errors.

Having this code as part of controller code, I would get `list_item.errors` contain `list_item.account.errors`, but that doesn't work in separate file.

I tried also

include `ActiveRecord:Association`

both inside and outside Array class (not sure if this matters), but it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ActiveModel::Model`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) is what you're looking for. It has already included [`ActiveModel::Validations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html).

But extending Array class with ActiveModel feels horribly wrong.